# Prevent one form to open Twice while Passing some Data

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms, reference

I'm working on a Inventory Software. In this Software when the user will press Ctrl+Space buttons then system will open a form (frmProducts.cs) showing all the products list. On this form user can search through products by name, select the product from this form and then press button Select. The selected product wll be shown on sale invoice product name text box along with the product code.

Now the problem is occuring when the user selects the product program opens a new sale invoice form and don't load the data into the old one. The program should show already opened form with the data filled.

The code I wrote to open the products info is:

```
  private void txtProductCode1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
               // frm4.Instance.Show();
                frmProducts cs = new frmProducts();
                cs.Show();
            }
        }
```

The code i wrote on frmProducts Select button is:

```
int ItemNo;
                string sql;

                if (lvProducts.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Select Atleast one Column", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

                else
                {
                    ItemNo = Convert.ToInt32(lvProducts.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString());

                    sql = "";
                    sql += "SELECT * FROM ProductLog WHERE ProductLog.ItemNo = " + ItemNo + "";


                    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
                    SqlCommand rs = new SqlCommand();
                    SqlDataReader sdr = null;
                    clsConnection clsCon = new clsConnection();


                    clsCon.fnc_ConnectToDB(ref cn);


                    rs.Connection = cn;
                    rs.CommandText = sql;
                    sdr = rs.ExecuteReader();

                    this.Close();


                    frmSaleInvoice frm = new frmSaleInvoice(ref sdr);
                    frm.ShowDialog();                   

                    sdr.Close();
                    rs = null;
                    cn.Close();
                }
```

and the code in frminvoice to catch data is :

```
public frmSaleInvoice(ref SqlDataReader sdr)
    {

        InitializeComponent();

            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                txtProductCode1.Text = Convert.ToString(sdr["ProductCode"]);
            }            
    }
```

I've also tried this code on Select button but it just don't load anything into the sale invoice:

```
frmSaleInvoice frm = new frmSaleInvoice(ref sdr);
                    if (frm.Visible)
                    {
                        frm.BringToFront();
                    }
```

and have also tried this

```
            frmSaleInvoice frm = new frmSaleInvoice(ref sdr);
            frmSaleInvoice.Instance.Show();
```

I also tried to pass value with `frmSaleInvoice.Instance.Show();` but it's not allowing me to pass data like  `frmSaleInvoice.Instance.Show(ref sdr);`

Please help me out, i am really stucked in it.

- either tell me how can i pass value thoguh instance
- or any other way to do this?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a public Class like i've Created fnc_selectbtncCode(); Data in frmProducts form and load data into this class using your db connection, just because it's public you would be able to access it other classes as well and can use it's data or just User Singleton Approach Just  like Zeeshan Suggested

// Use the Same constructor you have used Already

```
   InitializeComponent();

        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            txtProductCode1.Text = Convert.ToString(sdr["ProductCode"]);
        }            
}
```

and in form 2 the data you have loaded it's load event , load it in the public class

private void txtProductCode1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {

```
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            int a;

            frmProducts cs = new frmProducts();
            cs.ShowDialog();

            a = cs.fnc_selectbtncCode();

            txtProductCode1.Text = Convert.ToString(a);
        }
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        txtQty.Focus();
    }          
}
```

and the code of function "fnc_selectbtncCode" in frmProducts is:

```
  public int fnc_selectbtncCode()
            {              

                if (lvProducts.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Select Atleast one Column", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return 0;
                }

                else
                {
                    ItemNo = Convert.ToInt32(lvProducts.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString());
                    return ItemNo;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Thanks dude, very simple Solution ... thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

just follow the singleton approach.

OR

create a public function like loadData(parameter) in invoice form.
and then when loadData is called fill the invoice form with the new data

//use this constructor for first time
public frmSaleInvoice(ref SqlDataReader sdr)
    {

```
    InitializeComponent();

        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            txtProductCode1.Text = Convert.ToString(sdr["ProductCode"]);
        }            
}
```

for 2nd or any other time use

```
    public void LoadData(ref SqlDataReader sdr)
        {

                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    txtProductCode1.Text = Convert.ToString(sdr["ProductCode"]);
                }            
                Activate();
        }
```

Comment: can you provide some examples bro ?? or you could just update my code , I'll learn from it

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood way how you can propagate data from child form to it's parent.
There is many ways how implement functionality which you want (if I understood you correctly). I'll outline two of them:
First of all, lets define - your frmSaleInvoice is your parent form, and form which is showing after Ctrl+Space is child form.

1) Dialog way:
Change your method that shows child like this way:

```
private void txtProductCode1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                frmProducts cs = new frmProducts();
                if (cs.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //it says you that user didn't cancel child form without selecting item
                    //parent form is frozen until user finishes his selecting on child form
                    //you have to create some public property in child form which you fill after
                    //user clicks on Select then you can do following:
                    this.MyTextbox.Text = cs.SomePropertyIveCreatedToHoldData;
                }

            }
        }
```

2) With Events:
Second way is to use event, but I think that it is much complex way then ShowDialog. Also events lets you make this process to not freeze your parent form (it is not benefit in all cases), it is for situations when you want let user to manipulate with parent form while child form is active. While you have problems with this, you first should try ShowDialog way and then make decision if you want use event because it is really much complex way how achieve this funcionality.